# Find pattern and Replace in Unix using Sed / Awk

Tags: xml, bash, unix, awk, sed

In the below XML, I need to find timestamp in `<LastUpdated>` tag with single digit 0 millisecond and update them to 000. Trying Sed for this but keep getting error.

```
<Order>
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.0</LastUpdated>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderNbr>145645</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>STEVE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>05/08/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2014-03-28 10:09:04.456</LastUpdated>
</Order>
<OrderNbr>128965</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MARK</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>04/09/1989</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.0</LastUpdated>
</Order>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<Order>
<OrderNbr>136642</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MIKE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>09/03/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2012-03-28 00:01:02.000</LastUpdated>
</Order>
<Order>
<OrderNbr>145645</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>STEVE</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>05/08/1986</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2014-03-28 10:09:04.456</LastUpdated>
</Order>
<OrderNbr>128965</OrderNbr>
<CustomerName>MARK</CustomerName>
<CustomerType>NEW</CustomerType>
<DateOfBirth>04/09/1989</DateOfBirth>
<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.000</LastUpdated>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably get "error" because there's a `/` in your expression. But sed accepts any character as delimiter, just specify it after `#`:

```
sed -i "s#\.0</LastUpdated>#.000</LastUpdated>#" yourxml.xml
```

will do what you want (replace the string in-place in your file thanks to `-i` option. Note that if you have an older version of `sed` you have to redirect to another file & move it back to the original one)

Answer (score 0):

similarly with `awk`

```
$ awk '/LastUpdated/{sub(/\.0</,".000")}1' file > temp && mv temp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Command:

```
bash > echo '<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.0</LastUpdated>' | sed 's/\.0<\/Last/.000<\/Last/g'
```

Output:

```
<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.000</LastUpdated>
```

Update: This is only valid for "time" which has a single zero digit in milliseconds value. It will not work on values which are not single digit zero milliseconds values.

Comment: `$ echo '<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.220</LastUpdated>' | sed 's/.0<\/Last/
.000<\/Last/g'
<LastUpdated>2016-04-28 12:19:06.2.000</LastUpdated>`

Comment: Salut Jean - ca marche pas?

Comment: you have to escape `\.0`. Dot means any character in regex.

Comment: Oh, i got you. :)